# is there a way to see if there is a providerContainer still running in the uncontrolled provier scope on my android device

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to create an app for monitoring incomming sms's on my android phone with flutter.

I am relatively new to flutter.

I am using riverpod and I was trying to get a background function to communicate with a widget. I used the following code and ran it on my andoid phone.

```
final myNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_){
  return MyNotifier();
});
myNotifierProvider.MyNotifier.eventL

class MyNotifier extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Event> eventList=[];

  void addToList(Event event) {
    eventList.add(event);
    print("NOTIFY LISTENERS");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    UncontrolledProviderScope(
      container: providerContainer,
      child: const App(),
    ),
  );
  
}
```

I didnt get the app to work so I created a new app with a simpler UI to do the same job.  I did not include any of the code above in the app.

When I test the new app I see the phrase "NOTIFY LISTENERS" in the console when I receive a new message.  The new app does not contain this message.

I checked and the old app is not running, I have rebooted the phone - but I still get the message in the new app.

I have since read that perhaps I should have included a dispose method to dispose of the container when the app exited - or it runs forever.  I assumed this meant until a reboot, but I am not so sure about that now.

do you think the container is still running?  If so, any ideas on how would I stop it from running?

For the "NOTIFY LISTENERS" NOT to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this mystery myself. I thought I had removed all of instances of my previous app from my phone but I found that it was still installed. I guess I know what it means for the container to run forever now. The app wasnt running but it was actually still running in the background - this is interesting behaviour. Uninstalling the app completely fixed the problem